# C# SSL stream - certificate error after system reboot

Tags: c#, windows, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm building a C# SSL software, and it worked just fine when I first generated certificate using openssl, and eveything was good, until I reebooted my PC and ran the program again. In the line:

`clientSslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCert,clientCertificateRequired: false, checkCertificateRevocation: false);`

was the error `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The credentials supplied to the package were not recognize'`
I tried to reinstall the SAME certificate again and restart the program and it worked just fine.
after rebooting again, the program threw this error again. How can I solve the error forever? I'm using default windows certificate importer, and allowing every program to read the private key. I've imported both *.p12 and *.crt files but it wasn't matter. How can I solve the problem?

Here are some screenshot from mmc, on for the certificate on local PC account and the other for User PC account. The screenshots are **after reboot, when it doesn’t work**:
[image: local PC account cert info from mmc]

[image: user account cert info from pc]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer: In windows, after installing certificate you have to add valid user (e.g: Aviv, Admin..) to keep the certificate installed. 
Source: [Answer in serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/882728)